# Compare fields of two tables and calculate field

Tags: python, arcgis-desktop

Can you help me to compare fields in two tables?
I have two tables, which contain ID and Measure fields.
I need to take stroke by stroke values from field1(table1) and find all values in field1(table2) which are less than sought-for value. And then take largest of them and put it on stroke field2(table1).
Example showed on picture below.

It's will be great, if it would be python script.

[image]

Comment: I don't understand the logic you're using in your example excel table.  Can you explain more clearly how you declare values for field 2 in your results table? [This question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/27332/python-conditional-on-current-and-previous-row/27333#27333) may help you.

Comment: As far as I can tell, he wants to find the largest value in table 2 that is less than the current value in table 1.

Comment: Yes. And put in on field2 of 1st table ( stroke by stroke)

Comment: I assume these tables are much larger than shown.  What happens if the value of table1 is less than all values in table2?

Comment: then field2 will equal field1

Comment: It's all great but my table is only example( so there will be values less or higher then 11

Answer (score 3):

I'm a GIS guy, not a professional programmer so I'm sure there's a more efficient way to write this.  I tested the following code on the dummy data you provided.  You'll have to make sure it works on an extended dataset (hence the extensive comments so you can modify it).

**Pseudo Code:**

1. Create a python list of all values in table 2 using a search cursor.
2. Loop through table 1 with an Update cursor testing against each value in your new list.
3. If current value in list is less than the value of table one, store it in a variable.
4. If current value in list is greater than the value in table one, use the variable from the last iteration to update field 2.

**Script:**

```
import arcpy

# Put the absolute path to your tables / feature classes
table1 = r"C:\SomePathHere" 
table2 = r"C:\SomeOtherPathHere" 

# Create empty Python list
table2list = []

# Arcpy Search cursor
rows = arcpy.SearchCursor(table2)

# Get a list of all values in table2 field1
for row in rows:
    table2list.append(row.Field1)

# Delete cursor objs
del row, rows

# Sort the list in numeric order, get the highest value
table2list = sorted(table2list)
highestVal = table2list[len(table2list)-1]

# Create update cursor for table1
rows = arcpy.UpdateCursor(table1)

# Nested loop -- for each row in table1 we loop through our list of table2 values
for row in rows:
    # Reset stored value var for each loop
    storedValue = 0
    # If Field1 is less than the smallest value in table2, Field2 is equal to Field1
    if (row.Field1 < table2list[0] and row.Field < 11):
        row.Field2 = 0
        rows.updateRow(row)
    elif (row.Field1 < table2list[0] and row.Field > 10):
        row.Field2 = row.Field1
        rows.updateRow(row)
    # If Field1 is greater than the highest value, Field2 equals highest value
    elif row.Field1 > highestVal:
        row.Field2 = highestVal
        rows.updateRow(row)

    # When the value in the list is greater than Field1, use the last value to update Field2
    for i in table2list:
        if i < row.Field1:
            storedValue = i
        else: # This is where we're actually changing the value of Field2
            row.Field2 = storedValue
            rows.updateRow(row)

del row, rows
```

Comment: it's write that's some unknown problen has happenned

Comment: i was trying to set 9 or 8 in field1 and there are 50 in field

Comment: and when i'm writing 60 in field1 there is NULL value in Field2

Comment: Could you post your tables so I can take a look?

Comment: <img src="http://s24.postimg.org/jcqj47ckl/1st_table.jpg">  <img src="http://s24.postimg.org/8r6ns7691/2d_Table.jpg">

Comment: Edited: reset the storedValue variable before each loop of table2

Comment: now it looks like this <img src="http://s23.postimg.org/9yxbik217/New_One.jpg">

Comment: Edited: Account for when the Field1 is greater than the highest value in Field2.

Comment: Now it's work for values, which are greater then 50 and don't work for values which are less then 10

Comment: P.S. Values which are less then 10 equal 0

Comment: Edited: Account for when Field1 is 10 or less.

Comment: sry, but this table is only example, and it's can be that 1st valu will be much higher then 10

Comment: If your data isn't sensitive, why don't you post the files so I can test them directly.